# How does Java's Swing framework make windows / frames?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, window, jframe

I have always used `javax.swing` when I am creating GUIs in Java. To make a window, all I've had to do is write:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cool Application");
```

I'm curious - how does `javax.swing.JFrame` actually make a frame, and how does it manage to remain operating-system-independent? Would it be possible for me to create a frame myself without using `JFrame`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window creation is delegated back to the native OS implementation of the JVM.  The `Window` class is responsible for creating and maintaining a reference to the native peer (AKA peer).

The `Window` actually delegates to the `protected` method `createWindow` of `Toolkit`.  The default instance of which is initialized from the `System` property `awt.toolkit`, which is set by the JVM when it first starts

To you second question, I guess it would be possible, through the use of JNI/JNA, but I doubt you would actually be able to add anything to it, as the painting is managed by Java it self.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm curious - how does javax.swing.JFrame actually make a frame, and
>   how does it manage to remain operating-system-independent?

GUI in Java (valid for all PL) is created on peers implemented in Native OS, more description about details to see in [Windowing system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windowing_system)

> Would it be possible for me to create a frame myself without using
>   JFrame?

not possible to create Java Top-Level Container without JVM